# Send parameters to fallback Action in Polly

Tags: c#, fallback, polly, resiliency

I am trying to execute a request and return a response with 2 executers, using the Polly library with the Fallback policy.  Here is my code so far:

```
private IExecuter primary;
private IExecuter secondary;
private readonly Policy _policy;
public Client()
{
    primary = new Executer("primary");
    secondary = new Executer("secondary");

    _policy = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .Fallback((request) => GetResponseFallback(request));
}

public Response Process(Request request)
{
    return _policy.Execute( GetResponse(request));
}

private Response GetResponse(Request request)
{
    return this.primary.Execute(request);
}

private Response GetResponseFallback(Request request)
{
    return secondary.Execute(request);
}
```

The problem with this code is that I can't put a Request parameter on this line:
`.Fallback((request) => GetResponseFallback(request));`

And the code won't compile, because of the error:

> "cannot convert from 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' to 'PollyPOC.Request'"

How to make the code compile and tell the fallback policy that the action will receive a `Request` parameter to the `GetResponseFallback` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass data to your Fallback method you need to take advantage of the [Context](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-and-Context-Data)

For the sake of simplicity let me simplify your implementation a bit to show you how to use the `Context`:

```
private int GetResponse(int request)
{
    return request + 1;
}

private int GetResponseFallback(int request)
{
    return request + 2;
}
```

So I've just get rid of the `IExecuter`, `Request` and `Response` concepts to keep the sample code as simple as possible.

---

To pass data to your `GetResponseFallback` we need to change the parameter like this:

```
private const string requestKey = "request"; 
private int GetResponseFallback(Context ctx)
{
    var request = (int)ctx[requestKey];
    return request + 2;
}
```

So, we have retrieved the `request` data from the `Context`. Now we need to somehow pass that information to the `GetResponseFallback` call.

The good thing is that we don't need to modify the `GetResponse`. On the other hand we need to adjust the `Process` method like this:

```
private int Process(int request)
{
    var contextData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { requestKey, request } };

    _policy = Policy<int>
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .Fallback((ctx) => GetResponseFallback(ctx), (_, __) => { });

    return _policy.Execute((_) => GetResponse(request), contextData);
}
```

- We have created a `contextData` dictionary to store the input parameter in it
- We have used a [special overload of the Fallback](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Fallback/FallbackSyntax.cs#L86) where we have to define two delegates:

  - Unfortunately there is no overload where we have to provide only a `Action<Context> fallbackAction` parameter

```
public static FallbackPolicy Fallback(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, Action<Context> fallbackAction, Action<Exception, Context> onFallback)
```

- Because we don't want to do anything inside the `onFallback` that's why I defined that like this `(_,__) => { }`
- We have called a [special overload of Execute](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Policy.ExecuteOverloads.cs#L26), which has the following syntax:

```
public void Execute(Action<Context> action, IDictionary<string, object> contextData)
```

- Because we are not passing the Context parameter to the `GetResponse` directly that's why we can use here the [discard operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) `(_) => GetResponse(...)`

One last important thing: I had to change the `_policy` variable type to `Policy<int>` to indicate the return type.

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full source code:

```
private static Policy<int> _policy;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Process(1));
}

private const string requestKey = "request";
static int Process(int request)
{
    var contextData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { requestKey, request } };

    _policy = Policy<int>
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .Fallback((ctx) => GetResponseFallback(ctx), (_, __) => { });

    return _policy.Execute((_) => GetResponse(request), contextData);
}

static int GetResponse(int request)
{
    throw new Exception();
    return request + 1;
}

static int GetResponseFallback(Context ctx)
{
    var request = (int)ctx[requestKey];
    return request + 2;
}
```

Comment: So I had to do some tweaks to make it work:
I've added a circuit breaker policy:

            var circuitBreaker = Policy<Response>
                .Handle<Exception>()
                .CircuitBreaker<Response>(
                    handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 2,
                    durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            _policy = Policy<Response>
                        .Handle<Exception>()
                        .Fallback<Response>((context) => GetResponseFallback(context), (p1, p2) => { })
                        .Wrap(circuitBreaker);

Comment: and this is the code for the methods:

        public Response Process(Request request)
        {
            var context = new Context
            {
                [RequestKey] = request
            };
            return this._policy.Execute(this.GetResponse, context);
        }

        private Response GetResponse(Context context)
        {
            return this.primary.Execute((Request)context[RequestKey]);
        }

        private Response GetResponseFallback(Context context)
        {
            return secondary.Execute((Request)context[RequestKey]);
        }

Comment: @BudaGavril I've posted my answer too quickly. Please review my rewritten post.